# Determine minimum acceptable step in cut()

Tags: r, data-transformation

I'm using `cut()` to transform data like this:

```
N <- 10
table(cut(iris$Sepal.Length,quantile(iris$Sepal.Length,probs=seq(0,1,1/N))))
```

However, I do have many variables and I would like to determine what is the maximum acceptable `N` for variable. I thought this will be linked to unique values, but it is not that easy:

```
length(unique(iris$Sepal.Length)) # 35 unique values
    N <- 19
    ## Fails if N > 19
    table(cut(iris$Sepal.Length,quantile(iris$Sepal.Length,probs=seq(0,1,1/N))))
```

Is there a way how to calculate `N` or do I have to find this number iteratively?

Maybe this will be simpler case to work with:

```
N <- 4
x <- c(1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8)
table(cut(x,quantile(x,probs=seq(0,1,1/N))))
```

Comment: What's your goal with the transformed data?

Comment: I would like to use this as input to understand/plot relationship between variable and binary predictor.

Comment: Why not look at the raw data?

Comment: The quantiles need to be unique. If the quantiles are unique depends on the data and the probabilities (the latter being calculated from `N`). The algorithm used by `quantile` is not exactly easy to understand and I don't think it is easily possible to predict if the quantiles are unique without calculating them.

Comment: I suggest to change your question to something like "How to calculate the maximum number of equidistant probability values from 0 to 1 that result in unique sample quantiles". That would make it a better fit for CV and is an interesting problem.